# Hosting static Sharepoint site/aspx pages in Sharepoint modern site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using the approach explained in the article below to host our custom aspx pages to render Static sites.

https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2022/02/07/host-static-html-sites-modern-sharepoint-site-collections/

I would like to know if there are any known issues we should be aware of if we use this approach. As MS keeps changing the Sharepoint layouts/features/functionalities, we want to make sure we are safe to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to enable custom script, which is the prerequisite for a solution outlined in the blog post you linked above, you need to be aware of potential security implications which are well described in official Microsoft documentation. As the topic is related to security, I am posting link to the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-considerations-of-allowing-custom-script

Microsoft is not recommending enabling of custom script. Instead, you should consider implementing your customizations as a web part using SharePoint Framework.